# How to make a default value in combo box persist?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I created a form in MS Access 2007 for updating the user records in it.
I have one combobox in that form. I want to make one value as default. I'm selecting only one column from the query.

When the form loads it shows my default value. After submitting one record using button click it changes to the last value I selected for updating the record.

I want to show the same default value every time.

Query:

```
Public function bindcombo()
    Rs as recordset
    Strqry ="select menuname from menumaster wher menutyp='cutback'"
    Rs.open strqry
    With cbocutback
        .clear
        .RowSourceType = "table/query"
        .RowSource =strqry
        .ReQuery
        .defaultvalue="NA"
    End with
End function
```

I get the value in the combobox, and it is not showing my default value there.
It is showing "#Name?" (THIS VALUE INSTEAD OF THE DEFAULT VALUE)

These are my combobox values: rcCutback, loc-cutback and NA.

Comment: If you always want the default value to be "NA" why not just set it to that on the form control, and not bother with the code ? I can't see any need for all the code at all at the moment, unless this isn't the whole story. Also your With clause isn't referencing the combobox as far as I can see either.

Comment: I tried using the property box also. Its coming when the form is opening. After submitting one record it's changing to the last value i have selected

Comment: Let me guess - is this a continuous form ?

Comment: If it's unbound then you can't have different values on a continuous form, as it's got no field value to refer to, so your value will apply to every instance of the control. If it's able to be bound to a underlying value then it will work

Comment: Hi Minty, Can you please explain this

Comment: I'll try (without going round in circles), add a cmd button to your form, and it will have the same caption on every record, as it's not part of the underlying data, it's just a form object. So is your combobox and it's value, unless its control source is a field in the forms underlying rowsource. If it has no control source, then it's value is fixed for each occurance.

Comment: Minty, I'm fresher in vba, I have changed the row source and now I'm using the rowsource to query by selecting the control property box and selected the Data tab then in the 2nd row I have changed the query. in that property box I have changed the default value like this ="NA".

Comment: then it's coming when I'm opening the form or viewing the form in form view.

Comment: Okay - I'm not sure if that means it's fixed or not. By the way you are opening a rs in you code for no reason - it's not used, so delete that code.

Answer (score 0):

In Combobox's AfterUpdate property set the default value again.

```
Private Sub COMBOBOX_AfterUpdate()
    COMBOBOX = "NA" 'or any value you want to set COMBOBOX to

End Sub
```